# java.lang.String cannot be cast to TreeComparable

Tags: java, casting, comparable

`TreeComparable` is a `Comparable` interface.

The Error:

> ```
> java.lang.String cannot be cast to TreeComparable
> ```

This is the line giving me the error

```
if (((TreeComparable) r.getInfo()).compareTo((TreeComparable) p.getInfo()) < 0 )
```

And here is the method for that line:

```
public void insertBST(Object o) {
    ObjectTreeNode p, q;

    ObjectTreeNode r = new ObjectTreeNode(o);
    if (root == null)
        root = r;
    else {
        p = root;
        q = root;
        while (q != null) {
            p = q;
            if (((TreeComparable)(r.getInfo())).compareTo((TreeComparable)(p.getInfo())) < 0 )
                q = p.getLeft();
            else
                q = p.getRight();
        }
        if (((TreeComparable)(r.getInfo())).compareTo((TreeComparable)(p.getInfo())) < 0)
            setLeftChild(p, r);
        else
            setRightChild(p, r);
    }
}
```

Note: BST stands for binary search tree.

The `getInfo` method of the `ObjectTreeNode` class:

```
private Object info;
public Object getInfo() {
    return info;
}
```

and finally, I don't know if these will help, but my `TreeComparable` `compareTo` declaration:

```
int compareTo(Object o);
```

and the `compareTo` method in the `(Word)` class:

```
String word;        
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Word w = (Word) o;
    return this.word.compareTo(w.getWord());
}
```

The Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a [tour]. And if you can, try to put together a [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: getInfo is returning a String.  A String is not TreeComparable.  Makes no difference that a String is Comparable -- that does not make it TreeComparable.

Comment: So, even though the the class implementing getInfo only has Object variables it returns a string? I though upcasting was done automatically, and down casting was not. Is this where I am mistaken?

Comment: A String is an Object, so a method that is defined to return Object can return a String.  Now, if you defined `getInfo` to return a TreeComparable then it could not return a String,.

Comment: And casting an object reference *does not* change the class of the referenced object.  Unlike casting, eg, `float` with `(int)`, which actually modifies the value cast, casting an object reference modifies nothing.

Comment: I see. The thing is I'm want to avoid modifying data structures provided by the professor. This wish means I can modify the TreeComparable, compareTo(Object o), and the Object type sent to the BST. Also good point about casting Objects, and many thanks for the help. P.S. I want to give you rep, but don't know show.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `String` does not implement the interface `TreeComparable`. There is a an interface `Comparable` that `String` implements. String can be upcasted to this interface.

Comment: So, how do I fix it using the TreeComparable interface, and the Word class implementing the compareTo function?